# Ubuntu の Essential Package 一覧を取得したい

Tags: ubuntu, debian

Ubuntu は debian のディストリビューションをベースにしています。 [Debian Policy Manual - Binary Packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s3.8) によると、debian ディストリビューションには、 Essential Package があるようです。

Essential Package の一覧が取得できれば、どのような ubuntu システムでも想定できるパッケージ一覧が取得できると考えています。

質問:

- Ubuntu での Essential Package 一覧は、どうやったら取得できますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentialパッケージ一覧を私のところで表示してみました。

```
$ dpkg-query -Wf '${Package} ${Essential}\n' | sed -n '/ yes$/s///p'
base-files
base-passwd
bash
bsdutils
coreutils
dash
debianutils
diffutils
dpkg
e2fsprogs
findutils
grep
gzip
hostname
init
libc-bin
login
mount
ncurses-base
ncurses-bin
perl-base
sed
tar
util-linux
```

Comment: /usr/share/build-essential/essential-packages-list と一致した結果が得られることを確認しました。